How do I point a subdirectory of a website to a domain of another website?
I've got a website, let's call it blog.netlify.app which is deployed using netlify (SolidJS).
I've also got another website on example.com which is a static HTML page deployed using GitHub Pages.
Now, I want to create example.com/blog so that when users go to example.com/blog, they will see the content of blog.netlify.app without any changes in the URL address bar of their browser.
How can I achieve this? Do I need to configure cloudflare DNS records, or use Proxying or Reverse Proxying?
Also, I'm using absolute paths in SolidJS because my tsx files are like 5, 6 directories deep, and so writing ../../../../../../data/something.json isn't as convenient as writing /src/data/something.json, so I'm worried these assets will break when switching over, but SolidJS typescript will handle these absolute file paths, right? I've got
        "paths": {
            "~/*": ["./src/*"],
            "/src/*": ["./src/*"]
        },

configured in tsconfig.json, so netlify should work with that fine, no?
